# Fetch GKE "Security Posture" via API

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

In my GCP GKE cluster, I have enabled "[Workload Configuration Scanning](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/about-configuration-scanning)" as described in the linked docs and I see the Pod Security Spec concerns in the UI in the main menu "Kubernetes Engine > Security Posture".
I'm in need of pulling the list of configuration issues (called "Concerns" in the UI) via an API so as to access it from my automation portal.

Neither the [GKE APIs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest) nor the [Container Analysis APIs](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/reference/rest) seem to provide a way to retrieve them. The [Container Security APIs](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/containersecurity.googleapis.com) look promising but I'm not able to find any documentation for it. Would appreciate any info on how to retrieve it programmatically.

Comment: I believe you can only currently query concerns by running queries against the generated log entries:  https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/protect-workload-configuration#view-logs

Comment: @GariSingh thank you, yes, I did use the logs option to test things out. Any pointers to documentation for the Container Security API? We're OK with Early Access stage.